# How Do I Reverse An Array Recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method takes in an array of integers and simply returns that array backwards. Here is what I have thus far.

```
    private static int[] reverseArray(int arr[]) {
    int arrDup[] = arr.clone();
    int x = 0, y = arrDup.length - 1;

    if (arrDup[0] == arr[arr.length - 1]) {
        return arrDup;
    }
    else {
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrDup));
        arrDup[y--] = arr[x++];
        return reverseArray(arrDup);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrPass[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverseArray(arrPass)));
}
```

How can I go about fixing this method so it can reverse it properly? When I run it, I only `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]`. Assume that no elements in the array are repeated. I understand recursion, just trying to implement it here.

Comment: To implement recursion (or debug a recursive function) the first step is to state, in words, the recursive solution you want to use for your problem.  I can't tell looking at that code what solution it's attempting to implement.  You could start by explaining the recursive solution you're trying to implement, but I think once you do it will be clear enough to you how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should be the recursive solution

- Swap first and last number
- Reverse rest of the array

Swapping would require a temporary variable.

```
static void reverseArray(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    reverseArray(arr, start + 1, end - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reverseArray(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: I literally tried this before you answered the question! I should have spent a little more time on the problem! Thank you so much for the answer. Glad to know someone else thought like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the array length -1 and decrease by 1 till the half of the array. You can get the starting position by simply using mod(%) . Use Array length -1 for index when initial calling.

```
 public int[] reverseIt(int index , int [] main_Arr){
    if(index==(main_Arr.length)/2){
      return main_Arr;
    }

    int a =main_Arr[(main_Arr.length-1)%index];
    int b =main_Arr[index];
    main_Arr[(main_Arr.length-1)%index]=b;
    main_Arr[index]=a;
    reverseIt(index-1, main_Arr);
    return main_Arr;
}
```